# Sanatize title in url php

Tags: wordpress, search, sanitize

I'm trying to do a search based on the title.

Like this:

```
$alfred = get_the_title();
$link11 = "http://example.com/?s=$alfred";
```

The problem is:
When the title is

```
Account Manager (m/w) Software- / IT-Lösungen (non Microsoft)
```

it makes this url:

```
jobsde.de/?s=AccountManager%28m/w%29Software-/IT-L%C3%B6sungen%28nonMicrosoft%29
```

or when the title is

```
Recruiting Consultant (m/w)
```

it becomes `jobsde.de/?s=RecruitingConsultant%28m/w%29`

The wordpress search will not give me the results i want.
I think there must be a way to handle this properly, but i don't know how. Any thoughts?

I found [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_for_query)

I now have:

```
$title = get_the_title();
sanitize_title_for_query( $title );
$link5 = "http://jobsde.de/?s=$title";
```

That doesnt work.
The url still looks like:

```
jobsde.de/?s=HandelsvertreterPhotovoltaikSolarW%C3%A4rmepumpePhotovoltaikBeratersolarberater
```

What code should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

This will return all encoded characters to their defaults